# Applications of Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem?

Tags: real-analysis

[The Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) seems a bit too simplistic considering it considers only recognizing some "knowable" parts of some, even infinite, sets. That is, it recognizes that we can select some subset that's monotone and converges.

But where is this result actually useful?

Comment: It is used to proof the Heine-Borel theorem in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Cauchy sequences are bounded -> Bounded sequences contain a convergent subsequence -> a Cauchy sequence with a convergent subsequence converges -> $\mathbb R$ is complete